# How can I show data from one ViewModel in another View (table)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a table in which I would like to show the data that I have created in another ViewModel. The reason why I created this data in a ViewModel is that I don’t have enough knowledge to incorporate all that data in a single table. I will write only parts of my code because there is too much of it:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int IdCourse { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Students.Include(b => b.Course).ToList());
}

@using StudentCourse.Models
@model List<Student>
       <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>NumberOfStudents</th>   
                 <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Date</th>

            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Course.Title<td>
            <td>@item.Course.NumberOfStudents</td>
            <td>@item.Course.Description</td>
            <td>@item.Course.Price</td>
            <td>@item.Course.Date</td>
        </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

When a student selects a certain course, I should approve or reject her/his application (`Status` property):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.Status, "Accepted", false) Accepted
@Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.Status, "Rejected", true) Rejected
```

The number of approved applications should be shown by auto increment in:

```
<td>@item.Course.NumberOfStudents</td>
```

However, I am unable to do so but was able to retrieve data in a ViewModel with IQueryable/Key/Count.

ViewModel:

```
public class StudentCourseGroup
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Grouping()
{
    IQueryable<StudentCourseGroup> grouping = 
         from student in db.Students
                           .Include(d => d.Course)
                           .Where(d => d.Status == "Accepted")
         group student by student.Curse.Title into courseGroup
         select new StudentCourseGroup()
                    {
                        Title = courseGroup.Key,           
                        NumberOfStudents = courseGroup.Count()
                    };

    return View(data.ToList());
}
```

The data are shown in this table, everything is functioning:

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentCourse.ViewModels.StudentCourseGroup>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Title
    </th>
    
    <th>
        Title
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
</td>

<td>
    @item.NumberOfStudents
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

But I want `NumberOfStudents` to be shown in the join bigger table which I mentioned in the beginning:

```
       <td>@item.Course.Title<td>
       <td>@item.Course.NumberOfStudents</td> 
       <td>@item.Course.Description</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!  Before I answer, I think your data structure has 1 to many relationships between Course and Student.  It should probably be either many to many or 1 to many between student and course (many courses for 1 student. There should be a collection of courses a student belongs to in the student class).  As the data structure stands you will have to change `db.Students.Include(b => b.Course).ToList()` to

```
db.Students
                  .Include(b => b.Course)
                  .Select(b => new StudentDTO()
                  {
                      Id = b.Id,
                      FirstName = b.FirstName,
                      Course = db.Courses
                               .Where(c => c.Id == b.Course.Id)
                               .Select(c => new CourseDTO()
                               {
                                   Id = c.Id,
                                   Title = c.Title,
                                   NumberOfStudents = c.Student.Count()
                               })
                               .FirstOrDefault()
                  }).ToList();

public class StudentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int IdCourse { get; set; }
    public CourseDTO Course { get; set; }
}

public class CourseDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }
    public List<StudentDTO> Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: tnx a lot, will try that! - been almost desperate trying to figure this out:), thank you for the effort!!

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, it says: The entity or complex type  cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @ŽareLabud. I think you need to create DTO objects for the Entity Objects.  Answer Edited.  You can read more about as to why here. https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: still not working, message - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type...

Comment: Can you verify that the Course property in the `StudentDTO` is `CourseDTO` and not `Course`